# How do I remove the \paragraph{} text from the \tableofcontents with acmsmall?

Tags: table-of-contents, acm

I am writing a rather long literature review for submission to [ACM Computing Surveys](http://www.acm.org/publications/submissions/latex_style) and we are putting a table of contents on it for the benefits of our internal reviewers.  The table of contents is including text from the `\paragraph` tags. I don't want it to, but I can't get rid of it.

Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmcsur]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A SubSubSection}
\paragraph{First Paragraph} Some text.
\paragraph{Second Paragraph} Some text.
\paragraph{Third Paragraph} Some text.
\subsubsection{Another SubSubSection}
\end{document}
```

And here is what it looks like:
[image: table of contents]

I've tried to get rid of the paragraph text with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` and that doesn't help. (It removes the subsubsection, but not the `paragraph`.) I've also tried `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. No luck.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `\l@paragraph` (and `\l@subparagraph`) to do nothing (the class not defining `\l@paragraph` nor `\l@subparagraph` is a bug):

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmcsur]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@paragraph[2]{}
\newcommand\l@subparagraph[2]{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A SubSubSection}
\paragraph{First Paragraph} Some text.
\paragraph{Second Paragraph} Some text.
\paragraph{Third Paragraph} Some text.
\subsubsection{Another SubSubSection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the `acmsmall` class sets `tocdepth` to `3` (subsubsection level), paragraph and suparagraph title won't go to the ToC, so one can in fact provide a sensible definition for `\l@paragraph` and `\l@subparagraph`, in case one decides to include those entries in the ToC by changing `tocdepth`; in this case, one would have to say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. One day I will understand `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @vy32 You're welcome. Regarding `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`, you can read the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/3954